# Reading a file and replacing LF, but not CR-LF with python

Tags: python

I work on Windows and have a bunch of text files where some lines end with CRLF and some end with LF. What I need to do is to replace the ones that end with LF with `<br>` and leave CRLF as they are.

I tried regex `(?<!\\r)\\n`, strip() and splitlines(), but python always treats LF the same as CRLF.

What could I do to acomplish replace of only LF?

Thanks
B.

---

**UPDATE**

I checked your suggestions again, however they give me the same resulta as I mentioned - CRLF is treated the same as LF.

Im attaching the code I use alongside sample input file and the image of result I get.

```
with open(fileImport) as fp:
    testContent = fp.read()

    print("**** RESULT 1")
    print(testContent)
    print(" ")

    print("**** RESULT 2")
    testContent1 = re.sub(r'(?<!\r)\n', ' <br>', testContent)
    print(testContent1)
    print(" ")

    print("**** RESULT 3")
    testContent2 = testContent.replace("\n", "<br>")
    print(testContent2)
```

This is what I get using different options...

```
**** RESULT 1
----Row1;TX2829;Text Object;Value1
----Row2;TX2756;Text Object;"= 'Value in row 1: ' &
Num(
Sum(A)/
Sum(B)


, '#.##0 EUR')"
----Row3;CH246;Pivot Table;Title of pivot


**** RESULT 2
----Row1;TX2829;Text Object;Value1 <br>----Row2;TX2756;Text Object;"= 'Value in row 1: ' & <br>Num( <br>Sum(A)/ <br>Sum(B) <br> <br>             <br>, '#.##0 EUR')" <br>----Row3;CH246;Pivot Table;Title of pivot <br>

**** RESULT 3
----Row1;TX2829;Text Object;Value1<br>----Row2;TX2756;Text Object;"= 'Value in row 1: ' &<br>Num(<br>Sum(A)/<br>Sum(B)<br><br>          <br>, '#.##0 EUR')"<br>----Row3;CH246;Pivot Table;Title of pivot<br>
```

This is what i need

```
----Row1;TX2829;Text Object;Value1
----Row2;TX2756;Text Object;"= 'Value in row 1: ' &<br>Num(<br>Sum(A)/<br>Sum(B)<br><br>            <br>, '#.##0 EUR')"
----Row3;CH246;Pivot Table;Title of pivot
```

Sample file is available at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s81dibm8gxsfotf/TEST_FILE.csv?dl=0

Thanks in advace,
B

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?<!\r)\n', ' <br>', your_string)` should suffice.

Comment: Try `r"(?<!\r)\n"` instead of `"(?<!\\r)\\n"`. Also provide an example string you are regexing with repr `print(repr(string))`

Comment: Are you using `b` to read your file? (This is why providing a [mcve] is so important. Then we'd not *have* to ask.)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use `string.replace` Like:

```
string.replace("\n", "<br>")
```

Or Use [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/) Link.